# Произношение аббревиатур

Tags: фонетика

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно произносить такие аббревиатуры, как  и т.д.? Например, одни говорят "сша", другие — "сэшэа", одни — "фэбээр", другие — "эфбээр"? Как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общее правило: **буквенные** аббревиатуры читаются по названию **букв,** например: СССР [эс-эс-эс-эр], ЭВМ [э-вэ-эм], МГУ [эм-гэ-у], НТВ [эн-тэ-вэ]. Те аббревиатуры, что приводите вы, имеют некоторые произносительные отклонения, обусловленные влиянием разговорной речи. Так, за аббревиатурой *США* закрепилось по традиции произношение с разговорными названиями букв *С* и *Ш*: [сэ-шэ-а]. То же и в аббревиатуре *ФБР* – современные словари фиксируют в качестве нормативного прозношение с разговорным названием буквы *Ф*: [фэбээр]. Кстати, эта особенность есть и у других аббревиатур, имеющих в своем составе звук [ф], например *ФРГ* [фэ-эр-гэ] и *ФСБ* [фэ-эс-бэ].

Answer (score 1):

Общего и единого правила нет. Попробую дать некоторые статистические обобщения.
Буквы в аббревиатурах произносятся по их алфавитным названиям.
В случае сочетания двух букв для согласных звуков алфафитное название которых приводит с последовательному произношению двух гласных звуков следует делать выраженную паузу для разделения: **ТС**ХА (ТЭ-ЭС-ХА). Произношение типа "ТЭС-ХА" сейчас считаются устаревшими.

При этом: 
 1. Сочетание букв для согласного и гласного звука часто призноситься как единый слог: **ВУ**З, **ВНИ**И. Обычно это происходит в абберевиатурах, которые воспринимаются как слова.
 2. Аналогично, две подряд идущие буквы согласных звуков, могут читаться как единый слог или консонантное сочетание, если это оправдано фонетически: **БЭСМ**, **ДЗ**ОТ, ЗА**ГС**, **ФГ**ОУ, **МГ**У**ПП**, ТА**СС**, **ВР**ИО. 
 3. Буква Й читается как "йот": **Й**ОАК (ёак - Йошкар-олинский Аграрный колледж).  
 4. Начальная гласная в названии буквы может опускаться для начальной буквы аббревиатуры.
 5. Буква Ф, Ш, Щ, часто читается как Фэ, Шэ и Щэ, буквы С и Р тоже могут читатся как Сэ и Рэ, но значительно реже.
 6. Буква Л в аббревиатуре обычно читается твердо: В**Л**КСМ (Вэ-Эл-Ка-эС-Эм), **Л**ГУ (Эл-Гэ-У).